# React navigation 5: Undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

On my `UserProductsScreen.js` file, I passed a parameter id so that I can pick it up on my navigation:

```
const UserProductsScreen = props => {
    const userProducts = useSelector(state => state.products.userProducts);
    
    // Navigate to EditProduct
    const editProductHandler = (id) => {
        props.navigation.navigate('EditProduct', { productId: id })
    };
```

And then, inside my `navigator.js` file, I tried to check if it exist so that I can decide which header title to show either "Add Product" or "Edit Product":

```
  <AdminNavigator.Screen
                name="EditProduct"
                component={EditProductScreen}
                options={({ route }) => {
                    const productId = route.params.productId;
                    return {
                        title: productId ? "Edit Product" : "Add Product"
                    };
                }}
            />
```

I tested this if it receive the productId and it did but then, I received this error when click on the plus icon: `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.productId')`

I am not sure what it means but I am simply checking if it exist so that I can change the header dynamically.

For the record here's my complete `navigation`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import ProductsOverviewScreen from '../screens/shop/ProductsOverviewScreen';
import ProductDetailScreen from '../screens/shop/ProductDetailScreen';
import CartScreen from '../screens/shop/CartScreen';
import OrdersScreen from '../screens/shop/OrdersScreen';
import UserProductsScreen from '../screens/user/UserProductsScreen';
import EditProductScreen from '../screens/user/EditProductScreen';

import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
import HeaderButton from '../components/UI/HeaderButton';

const ProductsNavigator = createStackNavigator();

const ProductsNavMenu = () => {
    return (
        <ProductsNavigator.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? Colors.primary : ''
                },
                headerTintColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primary,
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17,
                    fontFamily: 'poppins-bold'
                },
                headerBackTitleStyle: {
                    fontFamily: 'poppins-regular'
                }
            }}>
            <ProductsNavigator.Screen
                name="Products"
                component={ProductsOverviewScreen}
                options={({ navigation }) => {
                    return {
                        headerRight: () => (
                            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                                <Item
                                    title="Cart"
                                    iconName={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-cart' : 'ios-cart'}
                                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Cart')}
                                />
                            </HeaderButtons>
                        ),
                        headerLeft: () => (
                            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                                <Item
                                    title='Menu'
                                    iconName={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-menu' : 'ios-menu'}
                                    onPress={() => {
                                        navigation.toggleDrawer();
                                    }}
                                />
                            </HeaderButtons>
                        )
                    };
                }}
            />
            <ProductsNavigator.Screen
                name="ProductDetail"
                component={ProductDetailScreen}
                options={({ route }) => {
                    const productTitle = route.params.productTitle;
                    return {
                        title: productTitle
                    };
                }}
            />
            <ProductsNavigator.Screen
                name="Cart"
                component={CartScreen}
            />
        </ProductsNavigator.Navigator>
    );
};


// Create a separate stack navigation 
// for orders 
const OrdersNavigator = createStackNavigator();

const OrdersNavMenu = () => {
    return (
        <OrdersNavigator.Navigator
            mode="modal"
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? Colors.primary : ''
                },
                headerTintColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primary,
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17,
                    fontFamily: 'poppins-bold'
                },
                headerBackTitleStyle: {
                    fontFamily: 'poppins-regular'
                }
            }}
        >
            <OrdersNavigator.Screen
                name="Orders"
                component={OrdersScreen}
                options={({ navigation }) => {
                    return {
                        headerLeft: () => (
                            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                                <Item
                                    title='Menu'
                                    iconName={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-menu' : 'ios-menu'}
                                    onPress={() => {
                                        navigation.toggleDrawer();
                                    }}
                                />
                            </HeaderButtons>
                        )
                    };
                }}

            />
        </OrdersNavigator.Navigator>
    );
};





// Create a separate stack navigation 
// for userProductsScreen
const AdminNavigator = createStackNavigator();

const AdminNavMenu = () => {
    return (
        <AdminNavigator.Navigator
            mode="modal"
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? Colors.primary : ''
                },
                headerTintColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primary,
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17,
                    fontFamily: 'poppins-bold'
                },
                headerBackTitleStyle: {
                    fontFamily: 'poppins-regular'
                }
            }}
        >
            <AdminNavigator.Screen
                name="UserProducts"
                component={UserProductsScreen}
                options={({ navigation }) => {
                    return {
                        title: "User Products",
                        headerLeft: () => (
                            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                                <Item
                                    title='User Products'
                                    iconName={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-list' : 'ios-list'}
                                    onPress={() => {
                                        navigation.toggleDrawer();
                                    }}
                                />
                            </HeaderButtons>
                        ),
                        headerRight: () => (
                            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                                <Item
                                    title='Add'
                                    iconName={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-create' : 'ios-create'}
                                    onPress={() => {
                                        navigation.navigate('EditProduct');
                                    }}
                                />
                            </HeaderButtons>
                        )
                    };
                }}

            />

            <AdminNavigator.Screen
                name="EditProduct"
                component={EditProductScreen}
                options={({ route }) => {
                    const productId = route.params.productId;
                    return {
                        title: productId ? "Edit Product" : "Add Product"
                    };
                }}
            />
        </AdminNavigator.Navigator>
    );
};







const ShopNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();

const ShopNavMenu = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <ShopNavigator.Navigator>
                <ShopNavigator.Screen
                    name="Products"
                    component={ProductsNavMenu}
                    options={{
                        drawerIcon: ({ focused, size }) => (
                            <Ionicons
                                name={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-cart' : 'ios-cart'}
                                size={23}
                                color={focused ? '#7cc' : '#ccc'}
                            />
                        )
                    }}
                />
                <ShopNavigator.Screen
                    name="Orders"
                    component={OrdersNavMenu}
                    options={{
                        drawerIcon: ({ focused, size }) => (
                            <Ionicons
                                name={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-list' : 'ios-list'}
                                size={23}
                                color={focused ? '#7cc' : '#ccc'}
                            />
                        )
                    }}
                />
                <ShopNavigator.Screen
                    name="Admin"
                    component={AdminNavMenu}
                    options={{
                        drawerIcon: ({ focused, size }) => (
                            <Ionicons
                                name={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-create' : 'ios-create'}
                                size={23}
                                color={focused ? '#7cc' : '#ccc'}
                            />
                        )
                    }}
                />
            </ShopNavigator.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

export default ShopNavMenu;
```

**Upate:** So I tried to use `setParams` on `UserProductsScreen` where the magic is happening. I use useEffect to set an initial productId to blank:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

const UserProductsScreen = props => {
    const userProducts = useSelector(state => state.products.userProducts);
    
    // Navigate to EditProduct
    const editProductHandler = (id) => {
        props.navigation.navigate('EditProduct', { productId: id })
    };  

        // Set initial productId params not until the editProductHandler is triggerred
        useEffect(() => {
            props.navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.setParams({ productId: '' }));
        }, []); 
    

    // dispatch
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

And then on my `navigation` I tried to catch the the productId via my headerRight:

```
    <AdminNavigator.Screen
    name="UserProducts"
    component={UserProductsScreen}
    options={({ navigation, route }) => {
        const productId = route.params.productId;
        return {
            title: "User Products",
            headerLeft: () => (
                <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                    <Item
                        title='User Products'
                        iconName={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-list' : 'ios-list'}
                        onPress={() => {
                            navigation.toggleDrawer();
                        }}
                    />
                </HeaderButtons>
            ),
            headerRight: () => (
                <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                    <Item
                        title='Add'
                        iconName={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-create' : 'ios-create'}
                        onPress={() => {
                            navigation.navigate('EditProduct');
                        }}
                    />
                </HeaderButtons>
            )
        };
    }}

/>
```

But this affects the id also on the regular navigation. Now the error is above is also showing when clicking the edit button.

Comment: can you push your codes and leave a link here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
     <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                        <Item
                            title='Add'
                            iconName={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-create' : 'ios-create'}
                            onPress={() => {
                                navigation.navigate('EditProduct');
                            }}
                        />
                    </HeaderButtons>
```

When you are navigating from the header right button you are not passing any parameters.

If you do not have access to route params at this point, you will have to use the setParams to set the parameters after you navigate to the page.
You can refer the doc
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop#setparams

Update :
so when you navigate wihout passing anything the route.params is undefined
when you access a property if undefined it throws an error

The way to validate this is to use the Optional Chaining like below

```
const productId = route.params?.productId;
```

This will set the value only if params is available.

Comment: Can I set the setParams inside the headerRight to false or blank like this to avoid the error?

Comment: So after this `navigation.navigate('EditProduct');` I'll put `setParams({ productId: '' })` or `    setParams({ productId: false })` is this possible?

Comment: no no you have to do that in screen level, maybe in useEffect or useFocusEffect

Comment: I tried to use useEffect to set an initial params for productId but its overwriting the navigation params when click edit.

Comment: Is there a possibility to create a snack, so that i can check ?

Comment: Why do you need a productId in userProducts param ? , from what i see its a listing page and you need the param only when you navigate using the headeRight,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219660/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-joan-buan).

Comment: As always you are a genius!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when my first screen loads. The **params were undefined** and I fixed it by using the `initialParams` option to set the params for my first screen.

```js
<Stack.Screen
  component={LCWebView}
  options={{
    title: 'Awesome app',
    myopt: 'test',
  }}
  initialParams={{ url: url_goes_here }}
/>
```